# How to extract alphanumeric phrase from a string with an alphanumeric phrase AND alphabetical characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column that can have the following possible values -

1. ITO26218361281- JANE
2. SBC28791827135 VATS
3. SOT21092832917 JOHN DOE
4. TIM INQ12109283291
5. JANE DOE 12/15

I only want to extract the 14 digit alphanumeric phrase from the strings that can look like above. If the record is like (5), I still want that record to exist to be able to call it out as an error. I don't need the exact text to be the same, I just need it to be flagged for error.

Result expected -

1. ITO26218361281
2. SBC28791827135
3. SOT21092832917
4. INQ12109283291
5. JANE DOE 12/15 (or flagged as error)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Regular expressions are not part of standard SQL, so if a database supports them, it uses its own bespoke syntax.  Also, edit your question to show the results you want, so the question is not ambiguous.

Comment: Poor design, those values should have been in separate columns.

Comment: @jarlh I totally agree. i did not design it :)

Comment: Are you aware that `INQ121092832917` is 15 characters and does not match your "_extract the 14 digit alphanumeric phrase_" request?

Comment: Is it guaranteed to be exactly one such substring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that you are working on a fairly recent SQL Server version and have access to the [`STRING_SPLIT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) function (SQL Server 2016 and later).

1. Split the values with the `string_split()` function. This gives you a `value` column to work with.
2. Remove the dash (`-`) from your first example row with a `replace()` function where required. If there are many random trailing characters you might want to prep you data a bit more.
3. The first 3 characters should not be numeric.
4. All remaining characters have to be numeric.

**Sample data**

```
create table data
(
  input nvarchar(50)
);

insert into data (input) values
('ITO26218361281- JANE'),
('SBC28791827135 VATS'),
('SOT21092832917 JOHN DOE'),
('TIM INQ121092832917');
```

**Solution**

```
select replace(s.value, '-', '') as result
from data d
cross apply string_split(d.input, ' ') s
where isnumeric(left(s.value, 3)) = 0
  and isnumeric(substring(replace(s.value, '-', ''), 4, 100)) = 1;
```

**Result**

```
result
---------------
ITO26218361281
SBC28791827135
SOT21092832917
INQ121092832917
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f93a6d8d122279ab6f0a45b8523cc5a1) to see things in action.

Comment: This worked, @sander thank you so much. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Hi, there are a few entries in my data that look completely different. For eg: GEOFFREY BRADLEY. (just a random name). is there a way that I can use your query to parse out the 14 digit code while also including such exceptions as is? 

Your query is filtering out the records that look like that completely (understandable as there is a where clause). I want to keep exceptions included even if they dont fall under the where clause category. any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, but this has great inpact on both the question and the answer. For example, how to distinguish between `SOT21092832917 JOHN DOE` and `JANE DOE 12/15`? Both contain a valid name... Best I could come up with is [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=a40b50b683d6a6b5f925cc75ecf0f2b2). If this does not work, then please _ask a new question_ and explain why the current solution is not working for you.